# how to prevent midpoints from extending

Tags: sas

I have the following code

```
proc univariate data=work.dataset noprint;
    histogram value / barwidth=.05 midpoints=(-2.45 to 2.45 by .05) outhist=data_bin nochart;
```

run;
I get this warning message in the log
WARNING: The MIDPOINTS= list was extended to accommodate the data.

I basically want to prevent the midpoints from extending I want them to start from -2.5 and end at 2.5.

**SOLVED**

Just need to bin the data before the proc step

Comment: They are extending because the data requires them to.  so if you have something outside of (-2.5, 2.5) then you require another bin.

Comment: @DomPazz you know what I did I limited the value to be from -2.5 and 2.5 which solved this problem. The problem is I only needed the data to between -2.5 to 2.5

Comment: Post that as an answer please, rather than in the question (and then accept it as an answer, in 72 hours).

Comment: @Joe dont have enough reputation to do that. I need more reputation to post an answer.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the reputation can you accept my answer I cannot accept my own answer for some reason thanks alot

Comment: Only you can accept an answer.  You will have to wait 72 hours to accept your own, however.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Basically at data creation point I cap the values of variable value in between the range of -2.5 and 2.5.

The code still remains the same just added a if statement in data to cull the data from -2.5 to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Use the maxnbin option to set the maximum number of bins you have. For example, endpoints = 0 to 2 by .2 maxnbin=10. This way you can keep your data as is.