# SAS: prevent ENDPOINTS from extending

Tags: sas

There was a similar question to this before ([how to prevent midpoints from extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008321/how-to-prevent-midpoints-from-extending)), but  does not answer my question.

I'm creating a histogram as follows and outputting it to a PNG file:

```
ods graphics on / imagename = "histoOne" imagefmt = png  reset=index border=off width=4in;
ods select where=(_name_ ?  'Histogr');
proc univariate data=myData noprint; *(WHERE=(sumStake < 250));
    Title1;
    var sumStake;
    histogram sumStake / name='histogr'  vminor=4 grid lgrid=34 endpoints=0 to 250 by 20 cfill=red;
    *Omit the inset, because the stats refer to the reduced dataset;
    INSET n (comma11.0) mean (5.2) median (5.2) std='Std Dev'(5.2) max='Max' (5.2)  / pos = ne
    header = 'Summary Statistics' cfill = ywh;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

I want to display both the histogram and the summary statistics inset. However, the data is so skewed, that it makes no sense to show the maximum value for sumStake on the X-Axis. I want to cap the X-Axis at 250.

SAS keeps extending the ENDPOINTS value. How can I suppress this?

I don't want to use the `(WHERE=(sumStake < 250));` filter as the count, mean, median and max in the inset will be based on the reduced sample, rather than the entire sample and will make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change your data in some fashion, or do the graph in a different way.  Histograms in SAS don't allow much mucking about with the data in this fashion; you have to do it ahead of time.  Histograms are meant largely for showing how your data falls out, so it's a bit counterintuitive to 'hide' some of the data fallout - I understand why you want to, but it is not exactly the primary purpose of histograms, hence why the functionality isn't there in SAS.

I don't think in any event that `PROC UNIVARIATE` gives you any ability to control this, so you may lose the inset.  You can control the axis length explicitly in `PROC SGPLOT` histograms (with an `AXIS` statement in `PROC SGPLOT`), but they don't have the same kind of inset - you could make something probably, but not as simply.  It also will still make the oversized bins, and won't reallocate those over-binned records.

Another option, particularly if you're making the inset separately anyway, would be to do the `SGPLOT` histogram (or bar chart) with data you've 'fixed' (right censored) and calculate the inset data separately (on the uncensored data).